# Localize javascript arithmetic operators

Tags: javascript, internationalization

I have a multilingual application that is "language" localized in terms of page content. But some forms are using simple arithmetic to calculate some field values based upon user input.

So 1.1*2 = 2.2 works but in Romanian where a fraction is written as 1,1 the calculation becomes 1,1*2 = 2,2 this fails as NaN.

So what to do?

UPDATE:

Thousands separators will be an issue. Look at this yui-library

[YUI Data Types](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/datatype/#formattingnumbers)

which has both parse and format functionality. Seems the "easiest" in terms of specifying separators as I'm "only" looking at 4 different languages. Though it poses an issue with HTTPS since application is serving HTTPS and Yahoo CDN does not support this so you have to self host and roll your own bundling.

Comment: Wait, are the users typing in this Javascript straight into the forms?

Comment: localization should come while displaying, NOT while doing actual operation.

Comment: @Asad The function is supplied by the application but the input is supplied by the users in their locale. So application supplies var sum = $("#A").val() *  $("#B").val(); But users are inputting values like 1 & 1.1 for english which is fine, but in ROM  locale they enter 1 & 1,1 for inputs A and B respectively which NaNs for arithmetic.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im O.k. So standard practice is to convert everything to english decimal, compute and then reformat the output?? If so where do i get a library that does that? I have all the globalization libraries for jQuery globalize which Im usig for dates but nothing for auto number conversion.

Comment: Ok well, my sum shoulda been a product but you get the drift. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Would something like the `unformat` function of the library numeral.js work?

http://numeraljs.com/

Comment: I will have a play and see. A quick skim suggests it works with currency symbols etc in english. Not sure if it auto-magically does l18n conversion of say 1,1 to 1.1 for computaton. Thx for link tho.

Comment: Example: `numeral.language('de'); numeral().unformat("1,1")` returns 1.1 correctly.

Answer (score 0):

if there is no thousandth issue, you can add regular in your code to replace ',' by '.'